# How to iterate through multiple responses from checkbox form item?

Tags: checkbox, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

I am dumping the selections from a checkbox question into a Google Doc. For readability purposes, I would like to parse each selected response and inject a line break between the selected options. Checkbox responses appear to be comma delimited strings. Some response options have commas in the text.

How do I add line breaks between multiple select response options?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)]` to find and replace the commas with line break characters. The line break character to replace will be `"\r"`

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#replaceText(String,String)

Hope that helps!!

Comment: The problem with this is some of the responses themselves contain commas. I don't want to replace those.